# I am trying to go in deep for understanding multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

> I am trying to go in deep for understanding multithreading in java.I
>   saw many suggestions to learn from great book "Java Concurrency in
>   Practice". Some also suggested to learn from the book "The Little Book
>   of Semaphores". My question is how much these two concepts are related
>   "Multithreading in Java " and "Semaphores concept or Synchronization
>   Concept of OS"? Do i need to learn both to understand multithreading ?

Answer (score 2):

The term "Concurrency" means that somethings runs in parallel. The way this is done in Java is by using multiple threads (ie "multithreading"), so those terms are pretty much equivalent.

The issue you have with programming concurrently is to keep your data consistent between the threads; this is done via locks (controlling access to shared data) and synchronization (making sure changed data is updated properly). "Semaphores" are the most basic concept of lock implementations.

So, pretty much learning one encompasses learning the other (rather than "learning both").

Answer (score 0):

The term "Concurrency" means two or more actions in progress at the same time,it doesn't mean they will be executing simultaneously